# Unity throwing NotImplementedException "Additional interfaces do not have an implementation." when injecting interface with AdditionalInterface<T>()

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, enterprise-library, ioc-container

I'm trying to use Unity to add an interface on top of an object without touching the existing code base.

The goal here is to apply some interceptors to an existing code base by simply configuring it in my application.

Things to keep in mind:

- I am aware that I could just apply the interface to all necessary classes. I just want to know if it is possible to apply all of it at runtime with my Unity configuration instead of modifying all the existing code.
- In this particular case, the interceptor is really just a pass-through, and I want the virtual proxy generated to have the necessary properties required by my **IWhatever** interface.
- The code I've provided throws a NotImplementedException, but from what I understand, the "Name" property should have been injected into the proxy.

Here's a code sample:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer()
            .AddNewExtension<Interception>();

        container.RegisterType<ICat, Cat>(
            new InjectionMember[]
                {
                    new AdditionalInterface<IWhatever>(),
                    new InjectionProperty("Name",""),           //checking to see if this will fix our IWhatever injection problem
                    new Interceptor<VirtualMethodInterceptor>(),
                    new InterceptionBehavior<VirPropInterceptorBehavior>()
                }
        );

        ICat c = container.Resolve<ICat>();
        string propVal = ((IWhatever)c).Name;


        Console.Read();
    }
}

public interface IWhatever
{
    void DoWhatever();
    string Name { get; set; }
}
public interface ICat
{

}
public class Cat : IAuditable, ICat
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class VirPropInterceptorBehavior : IInterceptionBehavior
{
    private object propVal;

    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        return getNext()(input, getNext);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Type> GetRequiredInterfaces()
    {
        return new[] { typeof(IWhatever) };
    }

    public bool WillExecute
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got two problems. The first is that Cat doesn't provide an implementation of `IWhatever`- even though it has a `Name` this is not an implementation of `IWhatever`'s `Name`. It won't be found on Cat. You can do something like this, but note it terminates the interceptor chain:

```
    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        if (input.MethodBase.DeclaringType == typeof (IWhatever)
            && input.MethodBase.Name == "get_Name")
        {
            return input.CreateMethodReturn(((Cat) (input.Target)).Name);
        }

        return getNext()(input, getNext);
    }
```

Maybe you want to store Name somewhere else than the Cat object - perhaps in a Dictionary keyed against object instances (think how the `DependencyProperty` system works in WPF).

The second problem is... and you'll kick yourself... you need `WillExecute` to return `true` to have the interceptor run.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you will have to write the implementation of IWhatever's Name in your behaviour VirPropInterceptorBehavior. Please refer to https://unity.codeplex.com/discussions/227719 for details.

But question still stands, how to take care of this situation? In your behaviour you will have to identify the call to IWhatever.Name and implement it there (in behaviour's Invoke method). You can do something like this. I have only implemented for GET, you can do it for setter.

```
public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        IMethodReturn result;

        // Taking care of implementation of additional interface IWhatever.
        if (input.MethodBase.DeclaringType == typeof (IWhatever))
        {
            switch (input.MethodBase.Name)
            {
                case "get_Name":
                    // Do your stuff here

                    // Make sure you do this to get rid of your exception.
                    // Pass the argument so that the calling code gets it.
                    result = input.CreateMethodReturn(input.Arguments[0]);
                    break;

                default:
                    result = input.CreateMethodReturn(null);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Do other stuff here.

            result = getNext()(input, getNext);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I hope it helped you.